# Inconsistent drawing (MPA Android Line Cubic Chart)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

I have used Line android chart with cubic mode but when it starts draw it shows inconsistent drawing:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cuE7.jpg)

this how entry list data looks like:

```
entry, y = 80.0, x = 2.0
entry, y = 51.0, x = 17.0
entry, y = 45.0, x = 19.0
entry, y = 52.0, x = 20.0
entry, y = 45.0, x = 21.0
entry, y = 80.0, x = 22.0
entry, y = 87.0, x = 23.0
entry, y = 80.0, x = 25.0
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to decrease cubic intensity on LineDataSet.

```
lineDataSet.cubicIntensity = 0.1f
```

Comment: Changing it works for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER)
lineDataSet.setCubicIntensity(0.05f) //(0.05f - min value)
```

[image]